# Django Serializers - Como actualizar campo PrimaryKeyRelatedField de una relación anidada

Tags: django, update, djangorestframework, serialización

Tengo los siguientes modelos

**El modelo Company:**

```
class Company(SafeDeleteModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addresses = GenericRelation('Address')
```

**El modelo Address:**

*En este modelo tengo una relación genérica de Address a Company. Company puede tener muchas Address relacionadas*

```
class Address(SafeDeleteModel):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='model_addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

**El Serializador Address:**

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only = True)
    country_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Country.objects.all(), source="country") #field added to get the id

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
```

En este serializador, `country` es el objeto del modelo Country, y he agregado el campo `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` con terminación `*_id` para obtener el id y usarlo para enviarlo desde el front-end si hubiera algún cambio.

**El Serializador Company:**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), source='category', allow_null=True)
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        addresses = validated_data.pop('addresses')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        address_list = []
        for address in addresses:
            address_id = address['id']
            if address_id != 0:
                address_instance = Address.objects.get(id = address_id)
                address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
                address_instance.save()
            elif address_id == 0:
                address.pop('id', None)
                
        address_list.append(Address.objects.create(**address))
           instance.addresses.add(*address_list)
           return instance
```

Petición JSON para actualizar Company y Address relacionadas

```
{
   "id":25,
   "category_id":1,
   "name":"COMPANY SA DE CV",
   "addresses":[{
         "id":1,
         "country_id":2,
         "content_type":36,
         "object_id":25 
   }]
}
```

El problema es que, si yo envío (PATCH or PUT) en la petición `country_id` o los otros campos de tipo `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, yo recibo el ERROR, ya que no aparece dentro de `validated_data`.
He intentado usando `read_only=False`, `write_only=True` en este campo pero no funciona.

```
    ...
    File "/Users/obedramales/Sites/webegin-project/webegin/app/serializers.py", line 214, in update
    address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
KeyError: 'country_id'
```

Esto sólo es cuando actualizo desde Company, pero si yo hago el update del campo `country_id` directamente sobre Address si funciona correctamente el update.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Comment: Una cuestión sin profundizar mucho en tu problema, aunque pueda estar relacionado, ¿Por qué utilizas una `GenericRelation` en lugar de una `ManyToMany` en `addresses`? Me ha llamado la atención porque este tipo de relación es para cosas muy concretas que creo que no aplican en este caso, a no ser que me esté perdiendo algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, utilizo `GenericRelation` ya que `Address` tiene relación con otros modelos como Contacto, Almacén y otros modelos que requieren una dirección y en algunos casos se necesitan múltiples. Había visto que de esa forma se podía resolver con múltiples modelos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenté cambiando la siguiente línea de código

```
address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
```

por

```
address_instance.country = address['country']
```

Y funcionó! Cuando envío `country_id` actualiza el correcto id, pero es necesario tener `country_id` declarado.

```
country = CountrySerializer(read_only = True)
country_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="country", queryset = Country.objects.all())
```

En la petición JSON tengo (sin `country`)

```
...
"country_id": 3,
...
```